# Return only selected data in PHP using Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

I am using PHP and HTML to develop a simple twitter API interaction. I am using the

```
GET 
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=rsarver
```

command. I would like to only return username, followers count, following count and location.

Anyone know how to do this?

```
<?php include "library/twitteroauth.php"; ?>
<?php
$consumer = "key";
$consumersecret = "key";
$accesstoken = "key";
$accesstokensecret = "key";

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumer, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
$tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=bandstring');


?>

<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset ="UTF-8" />
            <title>Twitter Search</title>       
    </head>
        <body>
            <form action="" method="post">
            <label>Search: <input type="text" name ="keyword"/>
            </form>
            <?php 
            if ( isset($_POST['keyword'])){
                $tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name='.$_POST['keyword']. '');
                        var_dump($tweets);
                    }          

            ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the REST API documentation https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

Comment: @RonniEgeriis I cannot see any mention of filtering out the information.

Comment: Then there's no support for it in their API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API will not filter out any information.  You will receive back the information you've requested as a JSON object and will have to parse out the information you require.